# GCP Compute Engine pricing calculation when running big-data programs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a virtual machine on GCP Compute Engine with Windows Server 2016, with n1-highmem-4 (4 vCPUs, 26 GB memory) and 50GB of disk size at europe-west2 datacenter location.

The total estimated cost of this virtual machine for one month is $272.45 if this is running 24/7 for this month.

My question is the following:

Will I be charged only this sum if I use this virtual machine for one month or it depends also on the applications which I run in it?

For example, if I want to run a python program which process thousands of images (by applying e.g. PCA on them) then will I be charged more because of the large amount of data I process in this virtual machine? Or the pricing is fixed from the moment you create the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

For Big Data you will probably be better using Big Data oriented solutions offered by GCP like:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/big-data

For BigQuery solutions there is a pricing list under this document:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

AFAIK, for Compute Engine instances, extra costs would be:

- setting up custom memory per vCPU
- adding GPU's to add computing power
- premium images like SLES or images that incur in licesing costs like Windows
- network traffic (you can check the prices here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general)
- load balancing an forwarding rules (prices here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#lb)
- local SSD disks (prices differ depending on the region)
- reserved and unused IP adddresses

I think if you need specific information on costs, you can directly contact sales using this form: 
https://cloud.google.com/contact/

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be precise, I was asking if there is any additional cost in running a vm except for the initial one which is determined by the size of ram, number of cores, number of GPUs etc....Except for this cost, is there any additional cost which depends on how much I use the CPU of this vm e.g. when I am running big-data programs etc?

Comment: AFAIK and as per the documentation tells, there are no additional costs derived from CPU usage.
But my guess is that if you want to run big data calculations the best way to go is to use the service GCP provides specifically for big query, because it's probably optimized for this use case, and if you want to run big calcutations on standard GCE instances you'll need to tunne it on your own.